# Recursive Palindrome Checker

Tags: java, recursion

This method only works for small inputs such as xox but not with a more complex input like taco cat. I have read this code repeatedly and have not been able to fix the problem. I assume there is a tiny error as I have changed the code structurally trying to tweak my approach and have not been able to fix it.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Palindromes
{
    static Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
    System.out.println("Enter a string, human:");
    String s=scan.nextLine();

    if(palindrome(s)){
        System.out.print("This is a palindrome, I am amused Earthling.");
    }else{
        System.out.print("Don't you know to speak only in palindromes to your alien Overlord?");
    }
}

public static boolean palindrome(String s){
    s.replace(" ","");

    if(s.length()<2){
        return true;
    }else if(s.charAt(0)==s.charAt(s.length()-1)){
        return palindrome(s.substring(1,s.length()-2));
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Have you tried setting breakpoints and using a debugger to step through the method?

Comment: `String`s are immutable. `s = s.replace(" ", "");`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two things to fix:

1. You forgot to assign the result of `replace` back to `s`, resulting in you ignoring the result with spaces removed.  Try:

   ```
   s = s.replace(" ","");
   ```
2. You have an off-by-one error when taking the substring to pass to the recursive call.  The [ending index of `substring` is *exclusive*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring-int-int-), so you are trimming one too many characters off the end of the substring.  Try:

   ```
   return palindrome(s.substring(1,s.length()-1));
   ```

Comment: Thanks you for the promptness. It's unbelievable to me the types of errors I make when working on my own projects versus school work, coding really is in the details. Someone commented that Strings are immutable as the reason to set .replace equal to the string calling the method. In this case this was dumb error as I know better implicitly. However, I don't know why this is the case _explicitly_, can someone please explain immutability in the context of java.

Comment: In this case, methods that look like they are modifying the content of the `String` aren't modifying the `String`, they are creating another `String` with the modified content and returning it.  No methods on `String` will change the content of the string on which it's called; this is by design and it is quite intentional.